# TypeError: value.includes is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using `rxjs` for filter and find the include value. but getting an error as `TypeError: value.includes is not a function` any one correct me please?

here is my function:

```
 fetchPaginatedList(pageSize, searchTerm) {
        return this.list$
            .pipe(
                map((list) =>
                    list.filter((item) =>
                        Object.values(item).some((value) =>
                            value.includes(searchTerm)
                        )
                    )
                ),
                map((list) => ({
                    size: list.length.toString(),
                    list: list.splice(0, pageSize),
                }))
            )
            .toPromise();
    }
```

what is the correct way to integrate the `include` with rxjs filter?

Comment: You are using `includes` correctly, it looks like your `value` may not be an array or string (e.g. a number or an object) therefore `.includes` is genuinely not a function. Find the type of `value` and work back

Comment: @nate-kumar - I guess because of getting `null` or `undefined` values makes this issue. if so how it can be handled?

Comment: `value?.includes(searchTerm)` will not call the function if the underlying value is `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @nate-kumar thanks for suggestion. but it works for me `   value?.toString().includes(searchTerm)`

Answer (score -1):

it should work:

```
fetchPaginatedList(pageSize, searchTerm) {
        return this.list$
            .pipe(
                map((list) =>
                    list.filter((item) =>
                        Object.values(item).some((value) =>
                            value?.includes(searchTerm)
                        )
                    )
                ),
                map((list) => ({
                    size: list.length.toString(),
                    list: list.splice(0, pageSize),
                }))
            )
            .toPromise();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

When you are iterating oveer an object it might be a number as well. Here is a small modification of your code to transform object value to string
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gvxvop?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

But you should understand that any complex structure, eg object as a property value, will break the code too.

Comment: mine is array of objects, ex:`[{
  sjmAccountId: 102729,
  hfsOnlyFlg: '1',
  phoneId: null,
  countryCode: null,
  areaCode: null,
  phoneNum: null,
  firstName: 'Ruta',
  lastName: '05',
  hfsStatus: null,
}]`

Comment: I've updated answer with proper fix